# Is it possible to canter a text in a cell after you have changed the cell's height and width?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a table rendered with matplotlib, I would like the cells to be wider than they are tall and for the text to still be centered. It seems, though, that while the text can be centered in the table at the outset, when I change the cell width and height to the dimensions I want (essentially a letterbox shape with very little vertical margins but significant horizontals margins), the text in the left column is left-justified and the right column's text is right justified. This is despite my using the statement:

```
cell.set_text_props(horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
```

I have tried multiple things to try to get the text centered and cannot solve it. Even if I try to set the horizontal alignment to 'right' in the left column and 'left' in the right column, it does not properly center the text.

Here is my complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

class SummaryTable:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def create_table(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.axis('off')  # Turn off axis

        # Get the data from the dataframe
        catchment_id = self.df['CatchmentId'].values[0]
        catchment_name = self.df['CatchmentName'].values[0]
        mode = self.df['Mode'].values[0]
        minutes = self.df['Minutes'].values[0]

        # Create table data as a list of lists
        table_data = [
            ['Location', catchment_id],
            [catchment_name, f'{minutes} minutes by {mode}']
        ]

        # Create the table
        table = ax.table(cellText=table_data, loc='center', cellLoc='center',
                         cellColours=[['#94c11f', '#94c11f'],
                                      ['#94c11f', '#94c11f']],
                         edges='closed')

        # Customize table appearance
        table.auto_set_font_size(False)
        table.set_fontsize(14)
        table.scale(1, 4)
        font_properties_header = FontProperties(weight='bold')  # Set font properties for the header row
        font_properties_normal = FontProperties()  # Set font properties for the normal rows

        # Set fill color for each cell
        for i, cell in table.get_celld().items():
            cell.set_facecolor('#94c11f')
            cell.set_linewidth(0.5)
            cell.set_text_props(color='white')
            cell.set_edgecolor('white')
            cell.set_height(.3)
            cell.set_width(1)
            cell.set_text_props(horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
            cell.set_text_props(ha="center")
            if i[0] == 0:  # Apply bold font to the first row
                cell.set_text_props(color='white', fontproperties=font_properties_header)
            else:  # Apply normal font to other rows
                cell.set_text_props(color='white', fontproperties=font_properties_normal)


        ax.axis('off')

        # Return the created figure
        ax.add_table(table)

        return fig
```

Comment: I think you are looking at a zoomed in part of the table, and hence the text appears to be wrongly aligned. Are you sure that you can see the full extent of the table? Run `fig.tight_layout()` to ensure you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

> I think you are looking at a zoomed in part of the table, and hence the text appears to be wrongly aligned. Are you sure that you can see the full extent of the table? Run fig.tight_layout() to ensure you do.

This is my MWE to reproduce the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [["Lorem", "ipsum"], ["dolor", "sit"]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis("off")
table = ax.table(data, loc="center", cellLoc="center")

for cell in table.get_celld().values():
    cell.set_width(1)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I remove `fig.tight_layout()`, I recover the behavior you observer:

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful. Do you know if there is anyway to add more padding to either side of the text within a cell? The image after you execute fig.tight_layout() is close to what I want, but I had hoped from an aesthetic pov to have more space to the left and right of the word in the cell. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You can set the subplot extents manually with `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.3, right=0.7)`, etc.

Comment: This is great, exactly the aesthetic I was looking for, thanks.